# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 's_id' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, find

I get from API two JSON :

First, are products:

```
 {
        "StatusCode": 0,
        "StatusMessage": "OK",
        "StatusDescription": [
             {
                "s_id": "11E8C70C8A5D78888E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "PkMGo",
                "active": 0,
              },
             {
                "s_id": "11E8C70FB9D10DB38E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "UgooX",
                "active": 0,
                },
              {
                "s_id": "11E8C7179F85836D8E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "IiLnM",
                "active": 0,
                }, .....
            {
                "s_id": "11E8C71905123F1A8E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "LVpcP",
                "active": 0,
             }
              }]
 }
```

Seconds, I have this JSON that get by product:
homeboxp

```
{
    "StatusCode":0,
    "StatusMessage":"OK",
    "StatusDescription":
    {"products":[
            {
                "s_serial":"PkMGo",
                "s_id":"11E8C70C8A5D78888E6EFA163EBBBC1D"
            },
            {
                "s_serial":"LVpcP",
                "s_id":"11E8C71905123F1A8E6EFA163EBBBC1D"
            },
            {
                "s_serial":"IiLnM",
                "s_id":"11E8C7179F85836D8E6EFA163EBBBC1D"
            }
            ],
                "hb_id":"11E8C71242B742EC8E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "active":0,
          }
}
```

In this part of code, I get all products form API, and find for products :

```
  product: Product;
  products: Product[]=[]

  selectedproducts : string = this.products.filter(
    x => x.s_id === this.product.s_id[0])
    .map(y => y.s_serial).join('');


    this.ss.getAllproducts ().subscribe(
      products => {
        this.products = products 
        if (this.products && this.products.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            let ss = products.find(x => x.s_id === this.homeboxp.products[i].s_id);
            console.log('ss', ss)
            if (ss) {
              this.selectedproducts = ss.s_serial[i]
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

I have error in this  `let ss = products.find(x => x.s_id === this.homeboxp.products[i].s_id);`

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 's_id' of undefined
>       at eval (edit-product.component.ts:123)
>       at Array.find () error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your implementation -

1. I think you have missed this `this` keyword for products in `find` function.
2. Wrong `index` value is being access. You should check if the product exist in the array.

Try this -

```
product: Product;
  products: Product[]=[]

  selectedproducts : string = this.products.filter(
    x => x.s_id === this.product.s_id[0])
    .map(y => y.s_serial).join('');


    this.ss.getAllproducts ().subscribe(
      products => {
        this.products = products 
        if (this.products && this.products.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            let ss = this.products.find(x => {
            let p = this.homeboxp.products[i];
            return (p && x.s_id === p.s_id);

            );
            console.log('ss', ss)
            if (ss) {
              this.selectedproducts = ss.s_serial[i]
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: The error doesn't show again, but `this.selectedproducts`  return only the first letter, not all value. for example `LVpcP`

Comment: Wrong condition in filter. You are always using 0 index.

Comment: Any idea how to implement?

Comment: I write this problem in new post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852560/filter-return-only-the-first-letter-of-product-selected Can you help me please?

Comment: Ok, let me check.

Answer (score 0):

You start your loop with index 0 until this.products.length. This is your mistake. You have to loop until **this.products.length - 1** because arrays start to count at 0. So the last access at **this.homeboxp.products[i]**.s_id is not set.

Change your code to:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length - 1; i++) {
        let ss = products.find(x => x.s_id === this.homeboxp.products[i].s_id);
        console.log('ss', ss)
        if (ss) {
          this.selectedproducts = ss.s_serial[i]
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I changed it, but nothing happens, the error is repeated.