# filter() return only the first letter of product selected

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, autocomplete

I get from API two JSON :

First, are products:

```
 {
        "StatusCode": 0,
        "StatusMessage": "OK",
        "StatusDescription": [
             {
                "s_id": "11E8C70C8A5D78888E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "PknGo",
                "active": 0,
              },
             {
                "s_id": "11E8C70FB9D10DB38E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "UgnoX",
                "active": 0,
                },
              {
                "s_id": "11E8C7179F85836D8E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "IinnM",
                "active": 0,
                }, .....
            {
                "s_id": "11E8C71905123F1A8E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "s_serial": "LVncP",
                "active": 0,
             }
              }]
 }
```

Seconds, I have this JSON that get by product:
homeboxp

```
{
    "StatusCode":0,
    "StatusMessage":"OK",
    "StatusDescription":
    {"products":[
            {
                "s_serial":"PknGo",
                "s_id":"11E8C70C8A5D78888E6EFA163EBBBC1D"
            },
            {
                "s_serial":"LVncP",
                "s_id":"11E8C71905123F1A8E6EFA163EBBBC1D"
            },
            {
                "s_serial":"IinnM",
                "s_id":"11E8C7179F85836D8E6EFA163EBBBC1D"
            }
            ],
                "hb_id":"11E8C71242B742EC8E6EFA163EBBBC1D",
                "active":0,
          }
}
```

In this part of code, I get all products form API, and find for products and filter :

```
 product: Product;
  products: Product[]=[]

  selectedproducts : string = this.products.filter(
    x => x.s_id === this.product.s_id[0])
    .map(y => y.s_serial).join('');




this.ss.getAllproducts ().subscribe(
      products => {
        this.products = products 
         if (this.products && this.products .length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.products .length; i++) {
        let ss = this.products .find(x => {
          let p = this.homeboxp.sensors[i];
          return (p && x.s_id === p.s_id);
        });
        if (ss) {
          this.selectedproducts = ss.s_serial[i];
          console.log(this.selectedproducts )
        }
      }
    }
      });
```

First error: this.selectedproducts: this return only the first letter of product selected, not all value. **SOLUTION**

```
this.selectedproducts = ss.s_serial[i]; to `this.selectedproducts = ss.s_serial;`
```

Second error: EditProductComponent.html:59 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined: n,,'. Current value: 'undefined: n,n,n'.
`selectedproducts` I used in html code like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let sensor of sensorsIdFormArray; let i = index">
    <input formControlName="{{i}}" id="sensors_id" type="text" placeholder="Select Product" [(ngModel)]='selectedproducts'
      aria-label="Number" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto1">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayWith">
      <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, sensor.s_serial, 's_id', i)"
        *ngFor="let sensor of filteredProducts | async | myPipe: products : 's_serial': i" [value]="sensor.s_id">
        {{sensor.s_serial}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </div>
```

My Pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'myPipe'
})
    export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform<T>(value: Product, list: T[], field: string, idx: number): T[] {
            const filterValue = value[idx] ? value[idx].toString().toLowerCase() : ''; 
            console.log(filterValue)
            if (filterValue && filterValue.length > 0) {
                return list.filter(sensor => sensor[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `if (ss) { this.selectedproducts = ss.s_serial[i];` but `s_serial` is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding two values city name and city id will not be possible for by textbox. However there is workaround for this if your city name is always unique.

1. Get the selected city ids.
2. Get the city name by city id
3. Set the formControl value with city name
4. From the screen, let the user add/remove the city name
5. Once user click on the Save/Register button, get the id by city name and set to the data you are sending to server.

Below are few snippe which can help you out -

> functions to get city name and city id

```
 getCityName(cid) {
    return this.city.find(c => c.city_id == cid).name;
  }

  getCityId(name) {
    return this.city.find(c => c.name == name).city_id;
  }
```

> Initialize form controls from the exiting city ids

```
 city_id: this.client.forEach(x => {

      x.city_id.forEach(cid => {
        //this.formData.push(new FormControl(x.city_id))
        let control = new FormControl(this.getCityName(cid), Validators.required);
        (<FormArray>this.myform.controls['city_id']).push(control);
      });

    })
```

> Before saving, Convert city name to city id

```
onAddprod() {
    let newHbp = this.myform.value;
    let mapped = newHbp.city_id.map(id => this.getCityId(id));
    newHbp.city_id = mapped;
  }
```

Here is the sample demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-bnhugp

Comment: I try this but My problem is when I use `[(ngModel)]='selectedproducts'` in autocomplete. When I have 2 products, in view show only third product in 3 different input , not 2 product. Like in image in post

Comment: You cannot bind Array to [(ngModle)].  You need change it to [(ngModel)]='selectedproducts[i].s_serial'

Comment: And you are binding the array for each iteration. Next issue you will come across related to asynchronous.

Comment: I try this, product are selected but in view doesn't show, and show this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]`

Comment: Put if condition in selectedproducts. `<div *ngIf="selectedproducts && selectedproducts.length > 0" *ngFor="let sensor of sensorsIdFormArray; let i = index">`

Comment: I create a demo, that illustrate my problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-dauesh?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts  I want to show in autocomplete name of city, and submit, id of city, like in add item.

Comment: Your demo is working as your requirement. What is the issue in demo copy ?

Comment: State 3, 4. I want to display name, not id_city. And save id_city.

Comment: Just check this modified version of your link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-cnzpsu

Comment: Yes, but it has a problem, when I add new item, I post names of the existing cities. Thank you!

Comment: Please, looks again, I add in code and remove items https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-vfbjty?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts  when I remove item, control doesn't work. Post name, not id

Comment: Have you any idea please?

Comment: I am running out of time now for free support. will look through later.

Comment: Update the answer and here is the demo link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-bnhugp

Comment: Thank you so mach dear Sunil. This demo doesn't work only when add new items, show `ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'city_id' of undefined`

Comment: its working in the demo link I given - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-bnhugp

Comment: Yes, works thank you... but when change for example client_name, and click register  more than 2 times, look that City_id is undefined, this because `getCityId(name) {` return id_city. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-ccqnnh?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts